# Stack photos on hard drive like Lightroom Classig does

Tags: lightroom, file-management, image-stacking

Lightroom has following feature for files loaded into its work environment.

> Automatically stack photos by capture time
>
> Lightroom Classic can automatically stack photos in a folder or a collection based on their capture time. You specify a duration between
> capture times to create a new stack. For example, suppose you specify
> 1 minute for the duration. All contiguous photos with capture times
> less than 1 minute apart are grouped in one stack. A new stack is
> created when the next contiguous photo has a capture time that is 1
> minute or more later than the previous photo's capture time. In turn,
> the new stack groups contiguous photos with capture times less than 1
> minute apart from each other, and so forth.
>
> You can specify a duration between capture times of 0 seconds to 1 hour. Specifying shorter durations creates more stacks. Specifying
> longer durations creates fewer stacks.

Is there software to stack jpeg files on hard drive into folders in same style?

Comment: This is exactly the same question as you asked yesterday.

Comment: @Tetsujin my bad i forgot i already asked it :)